# TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to follow the example from the JavaScript-for-Kids book(page 186-193), and getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined.

I'm pretty sure that the issue is related to jQuery object but keep getting the error on line 25

```
this.carElement.css
```

Please kindly point me out where I messed up.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cars</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">



let Car = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};
Car.prototype.draw = function(){
    
    let carHtml = '<img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/158575-200.png">';

    let carElement = $(carHtml);


    this.carElement.css({
        position: "absolute",
        left: this.x,
        top: this.y
    });

    $("body").append(carElement)
};
Car.prototype.moveRight = function(){
    this.x += 50;

    this.carElement.css({
        left: this.x,
        top: this.y
    });
}

let tesla = new Car (20, 20);


tesla.draw();
tesla.moveRight();


</script>
```

Comment: The variable `carElement` and the property `this.carElement` are not the same thing. Did you mean to set one of them to the other?

Comment: Apart from the above mentioned comment, you also need to parse the string into html to apply css using jQuery. `$.parseHTML(carHtml)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `let carElement = $(carHtml);` you have to write `this.carElement = $(carHtml);`, otherwise this.carElement is undefined, as the error says.